Why do some German surnames end with -ius?
I ask because the -ius suffix is mainly found in Latin and Lithuanian names. Examples of such German names would be: Gropius, Frobenius, Moebius. Did these people latinize their original surnames? If not, what is the origin of such surnames? They definitely don't sound German.

Apparently Frobenius is a Latinized form of Fröbel. Latinizing surnames was common when writing in Latin, as most people who could write at all did during certain periods of history. In any case, people have been migrating all over Europe for a long time, taking their names with them. So surnames are not a reliable indicator of nationality. If you want another example, the name Bernoulli sounds about as Italian as you can get, but the Bernoulli family was from Basel in the German speaking part of Switzerland. Their ancestors came there from Holland, and before that their origin is uncertain.

Did these people latinize their original surnames? It is also quite possible it was latinized for them. In a situation where someone else wrote down their name, for example a parish priest for the church registers, he might have been compelled to use a latin form. Sometimes, these forms stuck.

See https://www.namenforschung.net/dfd/woerterbuch/liste/?tx_dfd_names%5Bname%5D=1028&tx_dfd_names%5Baction%5D=show&tx_dfd_names%5Bcontroller%5D=Names&cHash=d30b89ef1af14caa2b3765f088f924b0.
